# Vertical Alignment of two inline-block divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs inside of a parent div and both child divs are display: inline-block. I would like to make it so the first div on the left is vertical-align: top, while the second div is vertical-align: bottom, but I also want to restrict the second div so it's first line of text lines up with the last line of text of the first div and extends downward increasing the height of the parent div instead of upward. How might I accomplish this?

For example, if I have something like so:

```
<html>

<body>
<div>
 <div id="d1" style="width: 50px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
Here is some text
 </div>
 <div id="d2" style="width: 50px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:bottom;">
Here is some other text
 </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the first line of d2 to be in line with the last line of d1. So it would look something like this:

```
Here
is
some
text Here
     is
     some
     other
     text
```

Comment: Give code lol :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align: text-top;` on the second div can approximate this

```css
#d1 {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: 0.1em; /* rectify the alignment*/
}

#d2 {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    Here is some other text
  </div>
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid red;font-size:20px;">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    Here is some other text
  </div>
</div>
```

Another trick using float where you need an extra wrapper:

```css
#d1 {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: 0.1em;
}

#d2 {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#d2:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
}

#d2>span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    <span>Here is some other text</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid red;font-size:20px">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    <span>Here is some other text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea in case the width are always known and fixed:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height:1.2em;
}

#d1 {
  width: 50px;
}

#d2 {
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -1.1em;
  transform: translate(50px); /* the width of the first div */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    Here is some other text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="font-size:20px">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    Here is some other text
  </div>
</div>
```

Another one with CSS grid

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height:1.2em;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:auto 1.1em auto;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
.container > * {
  width: 50px;
  grid-row-end:span 2;
}

#d2 {
  width: 50px;
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row-start:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    Here is some other text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="font-size:20px">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    Here is some other text
  </div>
</div>
```

In all the above solution you may need to adjust the `em` values based on the font used.

Comment: these don't really line up

Comment: @DCR that's why I said *approximate*

Comment: Thank you, the first example was the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one I used `grid` layout

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 55px 20px 55px;
  width: 65px;
}

#d2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="d1">
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    Here is some other text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: these don't really line up

Comment: the text overflow the container

Comment: he could just increase `width` manually according to the `font-size` of text anyway it is not good idea

Answer (score 0):

Use JS

```js
var d1Height = document.getElementById("d1").offsetHeight;

document.getElementById("d2").style.marginTop = d1Height-17 + "px";
```

```css
#d1, #d2 {
    width:50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#d1 { vertical-align:top; }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<div>
 <div id="d1">
Here is some text
 </div>
 <div id="d2">
Here is some other text
 </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```